# Call a Scheduled Async bean method in a running application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-async

I've got an Async method which is scheduled to run once a day:

```
@Component
public class MyClass {

    //myCronProperty set to "0 25 20 * * *" in application.properties
    @Scheduled(cron="{myCronProperty}")
    @Async
    @Override
    public void doDailyTask() {
        //Do work here
    }
}
```

Is there a way of triggering `doDailyTask()` for testing purposes when the application is already running, perhaps by doing something clever with Groovy and reflection?

I figure I can always tweak the cron property to 1 minute in the future in my `application.properties` file, and then restart the application - but just wondered if there was a smarter method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply inject the component into another class, for example a `@RestController`, and invoke the `doDailyTask()` method on it there.